# How to install PyQt4 in Manjaro/Arch Linux

Tags: linux, installation, pyqt4, arch

I've been racking my brain with this problem for about 3 days. I've been trying to install a printer driver which requires PyQt4 to be installed. However, I've tried every way I could find to install PyQt4 but to no avail. Does anyone have any solution?

Comment: Resent Arch/Manjaro has Qt5, thus no Qt4 related packages seems  available with `# pacman -S` .... Could you edit your question to show printer name/version ? ... and a link to "printer driver".

Comment: pyqt4 is not available in the official arch linux repositories but in AUR so it installs aur and then installs with `yay -S python-pyqt4`